# Cannot following official tutorial to install mongoDB on AWS EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I tried to install mongoDB on my AWS EC2 instance.

The linux version is:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2023"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="2023"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:al2023"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2023"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2023"
HOME_URL="https://aws.amazon.com/linux/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023"
SUPPORT_END="2028-03-01"
```

I followed the official tutorial: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/

But got error when I tried: `yum install -y mongodb-org`:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:24:24 ago on Wed May 24 21:06:16 2023.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.0-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.2-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.3-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.4-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.5-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-6.0.6-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-database-6.0.0-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-server, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-database-6.0.1-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-server, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-database-6.0.2-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-server, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-database-6.0.3-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-server, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-database-6.0.4-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-server, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-database-6.0.5-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-server, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-database-6.0.6-1.amzn2.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-server, but none of the providers can be installed
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-server-6.0.0-1.amzn2.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-server-6.0.0-1.amzn2.x86_64
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your linked document says `MongoDB is not currently available on Amazon Linux 2023.`. You're using Amazon Linux 2023.

Comment: OMG, you're right. Thanks, Sathyajith.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit and add this content to this file:
/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-6.0.repo

```py
[mongodb-org-6.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2/mongodb-org/6.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc

// add this block below

[mongodb-org-AL2023]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2023/mongodb-org/development/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-7.0.asc
```

then run this command:

```bash
sudo yum install mongodb-org-database mongodb-org-database-tools-extra
```

it should works